# File Redundancy in C

Tags: c, file

What is meant by **"File Redundancy"**??

It would also be helpful if a **"C Program to detect File Redundancy"** be also given.

I was asked the above question in an Interview. I didnt know the answer to it since I could not understand what they were asking in the first place. Can anyone help me!!!

EDIT : I have rephrased the question. I think I have made this more clear!

Comment: Can you please give a sample for context of this term? Where did you find it?

Comment: As currently given, I don't think there's any real answer to this question. You really need to clarify what you need/want before anybody can help.

Comment: What is meant my "C Files" with respect to this question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Pls see if u can understand it. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: From your clarification - maybe this term was used in relation to the specific business your interviewer is dealing with? I mean, if they are doing database programming then it may mean one thing and if they do biomolecular simulations it may mean something other? What was this interview for?

Comment: The interviewer mainly asked questions about OS and C programming only... So it would probably mean redundancy of files in disk!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably means duplicate source files.

Comment: I really can't provide a link here - there is nothing to link to... Just think of the case in which you have 2 copies of your main_file.c source file in you project (in different directories).

Comment: Ok... i can get your idea... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope they are not talking about the [Cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). The File Redundancy probably means duplicate files located in different folders on the hard drive.

You can write a program in C that would go through all the files and identify the duplicates.

Comment: So File Redundancy means having more than 1 file having the same data on the disc??? 

A C program to detect it means openig and checking each and every file to check if the same data is repeated then???

Answer (score 1):

This probably intentionally vague interview question seems to explore your knowledge of the term redundancy. I see several possible meanings of file redundancy here:

- Redundant (identical) replicas of a file to ensure availability in case of unavailability of a copy
- Accidental redundancy of the content of a single file. You can detect many cases of this redundancy by applying a file compression program to it. The more it compresses the more redundant the file content is.
- Intentional redundancy of a file's content. An error correcting code can be applied to data. This increases redundancy and allows to correct or detect a certain amount of errors in a damaged file.